# Why is my reputation shown to other users as less than my actual reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, users-page

I noticed that when any other user searches my name in the users tab, it shows a lot less reputation then my actual reputation. Only when he clicks on my profile, or visits my main page can he see my complete reputation. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Oh, by the way, there's a duplicate account of you. You might want to inform a moderator so that it get's merged into your account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a wild guess of mine:

[image: Circled the time controls in the user page.]